# Mock up is working perfectly in my machine but it is not working in server in JEST framwork

Tags: node.js, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, devops

Can somebody help me? I am wrinting unit testcase using JEST framework for nodejs. `It's working perfectly fine in my local machine but it's not mocking in server and my colleague machine as well.` I had google this issue and I found suggestion to change the o.s. I am working in windows base O.S. My colleague working in linux base o.s. I have tried to ran the unit test in my parallel linux base o.s. but it was working perfect in linux base o.s. of my machine. Please, Can anyone suggest me the solution?

Operating system : Windows 8.1

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack overflow, can you please add some more details regarding your question such as what specifically isn't working, any errors or error codes. Thank you!

Comment: I have set Pipeline on Github. I have wrote unittest case using JEST framework.I mocked few functions but Those unittest case are running perfectly  in my machine.Mocking is not working in github pipeline or other my colleague machine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found that solution. They occured unhandled promise return warning. That warning we must have to resolve. Without resolving that warning. It was working fine in my local but In Pipeline It's not allow because We have set some protol to not allow if any warning is there.
Thanks